# Regarding RNA seq data analysis and building coexpression network

Tags: rna-seq, statistics, networks, normalization, correlation

I have some questions regarding RNA seq analysis if you can suggest anything it will help me a lot.

1. I am currently normalizing RNA seq data for comparing genes expression within and between samples. Which normalization method would you recommend for this type of analysis? FPKM, TPM, TMM? Also I want to make a heatmap to see genes expressed in different conditions. Do you think transforming normalized data (like log2, z-score) is a good idea for this?
2. Also I want to build a co expression network, I am just wondering if normalization like FPKM, TPM, TMM  has any influence on building a coexpression network?
3. Another thing I want to do is use Pearson correlation but I am confused if it will only find linear relationships among the normally distributed data.  But normalization methods do not assume that counts to be normally distributed. So, Is it a bad idea to find pairwise coexpression of genes using pearson correlation? If so, which method would you recommend is reliable for building coexpression networks?

Please help me with this, I will be very grateful to you

Thanks in advance